# PhoneGap iOS getCurrentPosition while app is in background

Tags: ios, cordova, background, geolocation

I'm developing an app which tracks the geoLocation of a user using PhoneGap/Cordova. Knowing the users location even while the app is in background is crucial. I find a lot of conflicting information on google groups and forums. Some claimed it can work and others claim it doesn't work at all because Apple denies JavaScript to be executed in the background. Lot's of information is already dated and the hacks and workarounds I tried failed.

I added the "Required background modes" / "App registers for location updates" property to my projectname.info.plist.

My simple question is; is collecting geo information with a PhoneGap iOS app running is the background even possible?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Apple does not allow Javascript to be executed when the app is in the background. A possible solution is to create a phonegap plugin which does this without using Javascript.

Comment: Does this help? I haven't tested it, but it sounds too good to be true: http://www.thewebdevelopmentblog.com/2013/05/solution-phonegap-tracking-geolocations-in-the-background-ios/